# POST a Python list to a Node.js server expecting payload consisting of an array containing JSON

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

I am trying to send a POST request (in Python) to a server that is expecting an array containing JSON.  I can't seem to format the data properly.  How can I format the following payload to behave like a JavaScript array for a Node.js server?

**POST** /api/adduser/

Node.js expected Payload:

```
[ 
    {'user':'jon','email':'email@gmail.com'}, 
    {'user':'jon2','email':'email2@gmail.com'} 
]
```

My current code:

```
import requests
import json

payload = \
[
   {
       'user': 'hello',
       'email': 'hello@gmail.com'
   },
   {
       'user': 'helloAgain',
       'email': 'helloAgain@gmail.com'
   }
]

res = requests.post('http://localhost/api/users', data=json.dumps(payload))

#res -> 400 error -> reason:  "wrong json format - must be an array"
```

Comment: What happens if you try to encode the data as json?

Comment: Brian - This is what I tried initially, but I get the error, "wrong json format - must be an array".  The server that is handling the POST is nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected payload is not correct (it's not JSON). Save yourself tons of headaches and use the `json` module:

```
import json
res = requests.post('http://localhost/api/users', data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: thebjorn - That does not work.  The POST is processed by a nodejs server expecting an array.

Comment: Then you either need to set appropriate headers `Content-Type: application/json` (although I thought requests did that automatically) -- and/or call `JSON.parse` on the node side..

Comment: Great suggestion, though I do not have access to the server code.  I am writing python code to integrate with an external application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

**POST** /api/adduser/

Node.js expected Payload:

```
[ 
    {'user':'jon','email':'email@gmail.com'}, 
    {'user':'jon2','email':'email2@gmail.com'} 
]
```

My current code:

```
import requests
import json

payload = \
[
   {
       'user': 'hello',
       'email': 'hello@gmail.com'
   },
   {
       'user': 'helloAgain',
       'email': 'helloAgain@gmail.com'
   }
]

jsonPayload = json.dumps(payload)

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

res = requests.post('http://localhost/api/users', data=jsonPayload, headers=headers)
```